AttributeError: type object 'Task' has no attribute 'models'
It says my object Task has no attribute models, I tried to check if i had anywhere bad case but I don't think i have.
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import CreateTask
from .models import Task


def Home(request):
    return render(request, "Home.html")

def task_view(request):
    current_user = request.user.id

    task = Task.models.all.filter(user=current_user)
    context = {"task": task}
    
    return render(request, "task_view.html")

def task_creation(request):
    form = CreateTask()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateTask(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            task = form.save(commit=False)
            task.user = request.user

            task.save()

            return redirect("/Home/task_view/")
    
    context = {"form":form}

    return render(request, "task_creation.html")

models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

error block:
Django version 5.0.2, using settings 'task_manager.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

Internal Server Error: /Home/task_view/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lubos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lubos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lubos\OneDrive\Plocha\task_manager\tasks\views.py", line 16, in task_view
    task = Task.models.all.filter(user=current_user)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Task' has no attribute 'models'
[23/Apr/2024 16:59:12] "GET /Home/task_view/ HTTP/1.1" 500 63463

I tried checking if i misstyped anywhere but I don't think I did. Everything is in the same file.
Tutorial I went trough (didn't follow it altrough, since i had my own code, but i think i have everything same that should be):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Clf60pllEN8&t=490s

I think you meant Task.objects, not Task.models.

If i do that I get this error:
'function' object has no attribute 'filter'
also in the tutorial its used like I did:
https://youtu.be/Clf60pllEN8?t=1894

nevermind, found that he had mistake in his tutorial, he fixed it later

Task.objects.all().

The manager that all models (without an explicit) manager have is .objects, not .models, since you don't retrieve a collection of models, but of objects of these models.
Furthermore .all() [Django-doc] is a method, not a property of a manager, and in fact not necessary here.
Finally, you forgot to pass the context to the render engine of the template, so:
We thus can work with:
def task_view(request):
    task = Task.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'task_view.html', {'task': task})

I changed task_view in views.py to this:

def task_view(request):
current_user = request.user.id

task = Task.objects.all().filter(user=current_user)
context = {"task": task}

return render(request, "task_view.html", context=context)


the guy in tutorial made mistake and fixed it after
